# Save file to mongodb using angular and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image to mongodb using angular and nodejs. The code is below. I got the backend working but the problem is with the html input i get 'C:fakepath/file.xyz'. I was looking online and saw that there is not a way to get the relative path of the file. Can someone please tell me how i can change my front end code to get and send the file path to the backend to then save. I read that the browser doesnt allow relative path of the file but then how can I upload. Thanks!

The nodejs image save method is:

```
 async function SaveImage(userParam) {
    const entry = new imageEntries(userParam);
    entry.image.data = fs.readFileSync(userParam.imagePath);
    entry.image.contentType = 'image/png';
    await entry.save();
    }
```

The html code is:

```
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile" />
</div>
```

What I pass as the path in the backend is:

```
ImageJournal.imagePath = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myFile')).value;
```

but with the code above i get the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\fakepath\chapter9problemsandanswers.doc'
```

Comment: You can use formData to store the input file and then send it via http.post. Another way is to base64 encode the image and then send it as a string to the server. The server can then store it as a string. When you retrieve it you can convert it to image from base64 and download or display it.  I don't think passing a path will work. The server in a production environment isn't going to be able to read a file from your system. You need to send the file itself.

Comment: @GiwrgosLampadaridis thanks for the response, can you provide an example in my case. that would mean I will have to change my backend code method right?

Comment: Yes you have. I am currently on mobile, I will send you a sample when I get back in about an hour

Answer (score 0):

Ok here it is:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="pdf">PDF</label>
      <input type="file" id="pdf" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" (click)="clearFile()">clear file</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
public image;

 onFileChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      let value = <String>reader.result;
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.image = {
          filename: file.name,
          filetype: file.type,
          value: value.split(',')[1]
        };
      };
    }
  }
```

Then send the image with http post with a service.
On the server:

// send file

```
app.post('/api/sendFile', function (req, res) {
    File.create({
        filename: req.body.filename,
        filetype: req.body.filetype,
        value: req.body.value
    }, function (err, file) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else {
            const response = {
                name: file.filename
            }
            res.send(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This is written with mongoDb and mongoose and I have a model named File.
This is all it need to save it.

Comment: also how will I convert it back to an image once i retrieve it from the backend